# Embedding iFrame as Blogger Header

Tags: html, iframe, blogger

I need to embed flash `iFrame` as my blog header, but I have no idea how. I believe I need to put or change something between these parts:

```
#header-wrapper{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-       
H4DAZhwVcII/T9dOpEpsQ4I/AAAAAAAAG1w/mFQ_04it_vE/s1600/header.png);width:970px;height:140px;border:0 solid $bordercolor;margin:0 auto}

#header-inner{background-position:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}

#header{float:left;width:350px;border:0 solid $bordercolor;text-align:left;color:$pagetitlecolor;margin:0}

#header2{float:right;width:600px;margin-right:10px;text-align:left;color:#555}

.header .widget,.header2 .widget{margin:0 auto;padding:10px 0}
```

or

```
<div id='outer-wrapper'><div id='wrap2'>
<div id='header-wrapper'>
  <b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='RextraShop (Header)' type='Header'>
      <b:includable id='main'>
```

I'm sorry for my bad knowledge about HTML coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

> maxwidgets='2'

to

> maxwidgets='3'

(or some other larger number)

then you should be able to go into Blogger's layout tab, use the Add a Gadget feature, choose an HTML/javascript gadget from the list, and then paste the HTML for your iframe statemenet into the Content field.

Of course that won't help if your readers cannot display flash-based content - but there is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Actually I have change it from 1 to two. And, if I use javascript gadgdet, the iFrame will appear above or below the header instead of becoming the header itself. When I put it in header gadget trough layout tab, the iFrame didn't appear.

Comment: So you want to actually remove the header gadget as well as add your own?   If so, then change  true to false in     widget id='Header1' locked='true'     and then edit the gadget in Dashboard>Layout and use the Remove button.

Comment: Thank you very much...! All this time I never thought it will be this easy... It works perfectly... Thanks :D